# Is there a way to know when a program has just been closed?

Tags: winapi, window

I need to execute some istructions after that a program ( like notepad or firefox ) has just been closed.
Is there a way to know when a program has just been closed and then execute these istructions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acquire a handle to the process and then [wait for it to be signaled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Sine you talk about "closing" a program, I assume that the programs that are closed have a top level window.
Register a [shell hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_shellhook) in order to become notified whenever a window is being destroyed (HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED). You just have to check if the window belongs to the process you want to watch. You can use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net you should be able to do this by hooking to [Process.Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) for the processes of interest.

If you want to do this for ANY instance of that EXE that would be more complex.  You could do that using [WMI Events](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2006/02/11/438006.aspx) to monitor Instance Deletion on `Win32_Process` objects with a matching pattern.